# Rails 4 applying a scope for child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a scope that will return only the restricted objects of a parent object:

```
class BillingData
    scope :apply_restrictions, -> (restricted_numbers) {
        joins(billing_data: [:billing_data_lines]).where(billing_data_lines: {info_number: restricted_numbers })

    }
end
```

And calling it like this:

```
BillingData.apply_restrictions(restricted_numbers)
```

Will this work or just return anything that matches.  How can I refactor this scope to return the main object but with the filtered list of Child billing_data_lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to

- add `has_many :billing_data_lines` to your `BillingData` model if you haven't already
- change `joins(billing_data: [:billing_data_lines])` to `joins(:billing_data_lines)`

Then you can fire up `rails console` to see what SQL will be generated from your scope:

```
BillingDatum.apply_restrictions(123).to_sql
```

which will return (formatted for readability):

```
SELECT "billing_data".* FROM "billing_data"
INNER JOIN "billing_data_lines"
  ON "billing_data_lines"."billing_data_id" = "billing_data"."id"
WHERE "billing_data_lines"."info_number" = 123
```

The key thing to notice here is [the `INNER JOIN` keyword, which means that only the intersection of both tables is returned](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). So yes, you will only get the parent records that match the specified conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Association Extension**

You may wish to use an [**`ActiveRecord Association Extension`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)

Say you have some models which are associated as below; you should be able to set a custom method on the association to only return particular records from the db:

```
#app/models/billing.rb
Class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :records do 
      def only_today
         where created_at: Date.today
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/billings_controller.rb
Class BillingsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      billing = Billing.find params[:id]
      @records = billing.records.only_today
   end
end
```